# Why does not the generic counterparts of IList and ICollection have the same set of methods?

Tags: c#, generics, ilist, icollection

Is there a particular reason to why the generic counterparts of `IList` and `ICollection` do not have the same set of methods and properties? They seem to have moved them around.

Ex.
`IList<T>` has

```
int IndexOf(T item);
void Insert(int index, T item);
void RemoveAt(int index);
T this[int index] { get; set; }
```

But `IList` has

```
int Add(object value);
void Clear();
bool Contains(object value);
int IndexOf(object value);
void Insert(int index, object value);
void Remove(object value);
void RemoveAt(int index);
bool IsFixedSize { get; }
bool IsReadOnly { get; }
object this[int index] { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, so at least in the context of an `IList<T>` it doesn't matter which interface has what. As far as why, who knows what goes on in the minds of that crazy .NET team. However, it seems logical that a "collection" would need the methods to add, remove, check its contents, etc AS LONG AS those methods are not in the context of an indexed "list". Once you start talking about a list conceptually, you add indexing, which requires the indexer itself, and index-sensitive methods to add, remove and check for elements.

Comment: I totally agree with you that it makes sense that ICollection should have all those methods. Strange though that only the generic version has them.

Comment: @Magnus: The `ICollection<T>` includes functionality which should have appeared in a type between the non-generic `ICollection` and `IList`.  Conversely, between `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` there should have been a type somewhat like the non-generic `ICollection<T>`, but without the ability to add items.  Using the same name `ICollection` when the generic and non-generic things are so different is confusing; the best way to ease that confusion is to ignore the matching names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the major design decision came down to the fact that arrays in .Net actually all implement `IList<T>` implicitly. Many of the methods from `IList` such as `Remove` and `Clear` don't apply to arrays so they were moved to a different interface.

Comment: Arrays also implement the non generic `IList`

Comment: There is still an Add method in `IList<T>`, which is "implemented" by the Array.